# How to use tex -ini, tex -fmt, initex and fmtutil?

Tags: tex-core

What are the roles of each of these commands? 
What is the good command to create a new format ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `initex` command is on a modern system identical to `tex -ini`: I would favour the latter. This calls TeX in 'initex mode', which is the only way that TeX can be run to create a format as it enables the `\dump` primitive. Making a format 'by hand' is a simple case of running

```
tex -ini <filename>
```

where `<filename>` should be for a format file. For example, to build a LaTeX2e format

```
tex -ini latex.ltx
```

If you want to build a format with the e-TeX extensions enabled, you prepend a `*` to the file name (this requires appropriate shell escaping), and of course use a TeX derivative which has them. For example, for the LaTeX3 test material, I occasionally build a 'minimal format' with

```
pdftex -ini "*l3format.ltx"
```

Running `tex -fmt` requires a format name as an argument, and is used to get TeX to use whatever format you've created. So

```
tex -fmt=latex
```

would choose the LaTeX2e format (either the one I just created or the standard one installed in the main TeX tree). That will not be identical to running `latex` on a modern system, as the latter uses pdfTeX, so more like

```
pdftex -fmt=latex
```

Finally, `fmtutil` is a TeX Live tool for managing and building the large number of formats that a full TeX system has. It is used to generate the formats stored in the main TeX tree, which are used by default. For example, separate formats are needed for `tex`, `pdftex`, `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xetex`, `xelatex`, ..., and you would not want to have to change those all by hand. However, if you are building your own custom format then it's not needed.

Comment: In `makefmts.sh` script in [`cyrplain` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/t2/cyrplain), there is a command `pdftex -ini -fmt=cyrpdftex -progname=pdftex cyrtex.ini`.  Could you tell what it is supposed to do? Is the use of `-fmt` here an error?  When the script is run, no `cyrpdftex.fmt` exists, and the script produces a file named symply `cyrtex.fmt`.  Is there a way to specify to `tex -ini` the desired output file name?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to use initex is as a *pure* TeX. I use `luatex --ini` [for my software](https://github.com/speedata/publisher/blob/develop/bin/sprun#L132) because I don't need any extra macro definitions or a format such as [plain.tex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/base).