# Is it possible to create a new format file with commonly used macros appended to latex.fmt (Miktex)

Tags: pdftex, miktex, format-files

I use many macro defintions in my latex documents and many packages, which I want to be appended to the latex.fmt file. Is it possible to create a new format file with appended macros? And if it's possible how do I achieve that with MikTeX?

Where is the document included if I compile it with the new format file?
Is there any way to specify the inclusion-point?

To clearify what I mean:

Is it possible to include a file like this if I compile a file `document.tex`with `mypdflatex document.tex`:

```
% position of the latex.fmt and mylatex.fmt macros (e.g. the commenly used packages)
\documentclass{scrarticl}
\begin{document}
% position of the file which should be compiled
\end{document}
% some other definitions maybe
```

Comment: You can create your own format see e.g. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mylatex, but you will probably have to put the class in the format too as many packages should be loaded after the class.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51972/how-to-use-tex-ini-tex-fmt-initex-and-fmtutil

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Why do I need this package for creating my own format files?

Comment: I could add an answer how it works for TeXLive on Linux, but this would not be a real answer then

Comment: For the same reason that you are using other packages: so that you don't have to write all the necessary code yourself. "Dwarfs standing on the shoulders of giants" @davidcarlisle

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I thought of fmt-files being only binary memory dumps of regular tex /dtx/sty/cls files, so why is additional code required to make things working? there any literature explaining the creation of format files in detail?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that wouldn't be the real answer, but I think the tex-part doesn't differ between the distributions. I thought only the tools used to compile the tex-files and the way how they are included at startup differs.

Comment: @Sebi2020: Check the code. There is also a newer package `mylatexformat`.