# Add a package to default TeXLive LaTeX format

Tags: texlive, format-files

I'm using TeXLive (2019) and I'd like to add a package (namely [`kvoptions-patch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/kvoptions)) to all default LaTeX formats. What is the proper way to do this? Is there any downside?

Comment: are there any upsides? the time taken to load a package is negligible and if you add it to the format your documents will be incompatible with every other latex installation.

Comment: The upside is of course that you don't have to type `\usepackage{kvoptions-patch}` in your documents anymore, if you compile them on your own installation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As Marijn said, the upside is that I can use `key = val` inside `\documentclass` without the need to type `\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}` before `\documentclass`.

Comment: sure but the price of making your document not a latex document and unusable in any standard latex installation seems far too high a price to pay.

Comment: In addition to what @DavidCarlisle says, doing this could effectively prevent you from sharing documents with anyone else.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it would only prevent sharing documents that actually use key-val options, other documents would be fine. Also it would be trivial to fix the document when it needs to be shared. So there might be a valid use case here as long as the OP understands the consequences.

Comment: I would create a new format file based on the `latex` format with that package pre-loaded, see the comments on [Is it possible to create a new format file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268087/is-it-possible-to-create-a-new-format-file-with-commonly-used-macros-appended-to)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the format is not recommended because it breaks compatibility, as noted in the comments. However, if you still want to use an approach like this, and assuming you use Linux (given the [texlive](/questions/tagged/texlive) tag) then an easy way to proceed is by using a bash script that automatically loads the package before loading the document itself. The basic idea is to run `pdflatex "\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}\input{yourfile.tex}"` instead of `pdflatex yourfile.tex`, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1495/ for more discussion on this approach. Note that I use `pdflatex` as an example but it works the same for `xelatex` and `lualatex` with the necessary modifications to the script below.

This script should be able to handle command line arguments and insert them in between the command itself and the document string, so you need some bash argument processing in the script.

Furthermore the input as string changes the jobname, i.e., the string that `pdflatex` uses to create the filename of the output pdf. To use the original filename the command line option `--jobname` has to be set explicitly.

Finally you can alias the normal compiler command to the script to keep the same workflow as you had before. Put this in your `.bashrc` to make it permanent.

Script, called `myscript.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function mypdflatex(){
mycmd="\pdflatex --jobname=$(basename "${!#}" .tex) "${*%${!#}}" \"\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}\input{${!#}}\""
eval "$mycmd"
}
```

Load the script and create the alias:

```bash
source myscript.sh
alias pdflatex=mypdflatex
```

Example document `kvdummy.tex`, that produces an error without `kvoptions-patch`:

```
\documentclass[pdfauthor=Fran\c coise M\"uller]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Compiling the document (`shell-escape` for illustration only, this is not needed to run the example):

```
$ pdflatex --shell-escape kvdummy.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions-patch.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))
(./kvdummy.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
...
Output written on kvdummy.pdf (1 page, 10434 bytes).
Transcript written on kvdummy.log.
```

Comment: Thanks Marijn (+1). Interesting approach indeed.